# Are there functions that converge to $P$ when $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ and to $Q$ when $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with $Q\neq P$?

Tags: analysis

I remember that my professor gave one example of a function that when $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$, this function converged to a number, say, $P$. And when $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, it also converged to the same number. I got curious on one thing: Are there functions that converges to $P$ when $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ and to $Q$ when $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with $Q\neq P$? I'm using $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ as the domains, but if you know something about any other domain, I'm open to read it too.

The nearest idea I have about this is the Gamma function, which I've read that is the analytic continuation of the factorial function. I guess that this function might present this kind of behavior.

Comment: $f(x)=\sin(\pi x)$ converges to $0$ when domain is $\mathbb{N}$ and it diverges in  $\mathbb{R}$. But I think if a function converges to a real number P in $\mathbb{R}$ it will also converge to same number P in $\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 3):

I guess that you are referring to convergence for $x\rightarrow \infty$ in one case as $x \in \mathbb{N}$ (so we interpret everything as convergence of sequences) and in the other case as $x \in \Bbb{R}$ (so we interpret the limit as a "continuous" limit).

In that case, the behaviour you want can not occur, that is you will always have $P = Q$.

For a proof note that $f(x) \rightarrow Q$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$ (as a continuous limit) means that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is some $R > 0$ such that $|f(x) - Q| < \varepsilon$ holds for all $x \geq R$.

But this implies in particular that for $n \in \Bbb{N}$ with $n \geq \lceil R \rceil$ we have $|f(n) - Q| < \varepsilon$. This show that we also have $f(n) \rightarrow Q$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$.

As the limit of $f(n)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ is unique, you get $P=Q$.

Answer (score 2):

The only examples, would be functions that have a limit, when $f:\Bbb N\to \Bbb R$, but they have no limit when $f:\Bbb R^+_0\to \Bbb R$, consider $f:\Bbb N\to \Bbb R$, where $f(x)=\sin(\pi x)$, here  the limit is $0$.

But if $f:\Bbb R^+_0\to \Bbb R$, then there is no limit.